# How to write data greater than 256 bytes to a DESFire NFC card using the MIFARE SDK Lite?

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare

I'm working on a project where I need to write data securely to a DESFire card. I was able to format/personalize/authenticate and write data. But since I'm using the lite version of the SDK, I can't seem to write more than 256 bytes. When I do, I get this error:

`com.nxp.nfclib.exceptions.SmartCardException: File length of 256 bytes is only supported in Lite Version.`

I'm running the following commands/methods:

```
mDESFire.getReader().close();
mDESFire.getReader().connect();
mDESFire.getReader().setTimeout(2000);
mDESFire.format(Constants.DESFIRE_MASTER_KEY);
mDESFire.getReader().setTimeout(2000);
mDESFire.personalize(Constants.DESFIRE_MASTER_KEY, Constants.PRIVATE_PROFILE_APP_ID, Constants.PRIVATE_PROFILE_APP_KEY);
mDESFire.getReader().setTimeout(2000);
mDESFire.write(myString.getBytes());
```

I assume I can achieve this using the method `mDESFire.getReader().transceive()` but would I need to do my own encryption/decryption in this case? I'm kinda new to NFC in general so I'm not really sure what steps to take next. I tried going through the card's [datasheet](http://neteril.org/files/M075031_desfire.pdf), which got me more lost and unfortunately, getting the full/pro SDK is not really an option in my case.